# Updating Realm object with optional string property to be nil?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a Realm model defined like this:

```
class Contact: Object {
   dynamic var id: -1
   dynamic var alias: String?

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "id"
   }
}
```

My code downloads JSON from a server and adds/updates contacts in my Realm database.  After JSON deserialization, I end up with an array of contact objects.  I iterate through the array and check to see if each contact is already in the database and if so, whether it's 'alias' property matches the value on the deserialized object.  For the sake of example, let's assume that I have a contact in my database with an 'alias' property value of "John Smith".  The next time I get updated data from the server, the 'alias' property is now missing from the JSON for this contact so the .alias property on my deserialized contact object will be nil.  Now I need to update the existing contact in Realm so it's .alias property is also nil (instead of "John Smith").  I'm attempting to do this as follows:

```
// existingContact.alias = "John Smith"
// contactFromServer.alias = nil

if existingContact.alias != contactFromServer.alias {
   try realm.write {
      realm.create(Contact.self, value: ["id" : contactFromServer.id, "alias" : contactFromServer.alias], update: true)
   }
}
```

When this code executes, I'm getting an RLMException that indicates, "Invalid value 'nil' for property 'alias'".  This code works as expected when the .alias property of the existing contact is nil and I update it to a String value (like "John Smith").  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I thought that since alias is declared as an optional String, I'd be able to update it to a value of nil?

**Update:**

I just tried manually setting `contactFromServer.alias = "TEST"` right before the call to `realm.create()` and I'm still getting the same exception (just replace 'nil' with Optional("TEST") in the error message above).  I'm obviously doing something wrong here.  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a Swift 3.0 limitation when `nil` is bridged to `Any`. [SE-0140](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md) addresses this in Swift 3.0.1 by bridging `nil` to `NSNull()`. In the meantime, you can do this yourself by specifying `contactFromServer.alias ?? NSNull()`:

```
if existingContact.alias != contactFromServer.alias {
    try realm.write {
        realm.create(Contact.self, value: ["id" : contactFromServer.id, "alias" : contactFromServer.alias ?? NSNull()], update: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  When I make this change, the compiler gives me this error: "Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal"